# Resize jquery UI dialog with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Even better would be if `autoResize` in latest branch would work as intended, but till then the question is simple: **how to resize a dialog once it is created?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer from is Soviut is correct for `v1.5. 1.6` adds an `option` method to each plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = $("#example").dialog();
    d.dialog("option", "width", 700);
});
```

Comment: I think the first `dialog()` call should be removed in this example.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#dialog').dialog().animate({width: "700px"}, 400);
```

I've used this for dynamically resizing dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

All JQuery UI plugins can have their properties updated using .data():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = $("#example").dialog();
    d.data("width.dialog", 700);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

But the contents of the dialog (.ui-dialog-content) do not follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have the dialog sized to contents when created so I use this:

```
var dlg = $("#dialog");
dlg.dialog( {
    width: 600,
    height: dlg.height() + 100
    });
```